# SQL Add foreign key to existing column

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

If I am using the following SQL command in SQL Server 2008 to update a table with a foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
REFERENCES ActiveDirectories(id)
```

**`UserID`** being my FK column in the `Employees` table. I'm trying to reference the **`UserID`** in my `ActiveDirectories` table. I receive this error:

> Foreign key 'UserID' references invalid column 'UserID' in referencing
>   table 'Employees'.

Comment: Could you provide your two table's schema?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196951/how-can-id-assign-foreign-key-mysqli/35197004#35197004

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Error indicates that there is no UserID column in your Employees table. Try adding the column first and then re-run the statement.

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ActiveDirectories_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
    REFERENCES ActiveDirectories(id);
```

Comment: This was correct. Our DB was not updating our add column. This has been resolved but not that our column is established I still can not add the constraint. `There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'ActiveDirectories' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Employees__UserI__04E4BC85'.`

Comment: Looks like whichever column is referenced by FK__Employees__UserI__04E4BC85 is not defined as PRIMARY KEY or candidate key in ActiveDirectories table.

Comment: yea but it is definitely our PK in the ActiveDirectories table

Comment: RESOLVED: There is a reason why you create ERDs and establish relationships prior to building. We had too many records in one table which caused an error trying to create the relationships to the other table. Thanks all.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196951/how-can-id-assign-foreign-key-mysqli/35197004#35197004

Comment: Thanks this worked, For future readers a **Note:** Please be sure that values of foreign keys of both the table match, otherwise you get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839309/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint) warning.

Comment: You can add `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Answer (score 25):

Maybe you got your columns backwards??

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD FOREIGN KEY (UserID)           <-- this needs to be a column of the Employees table
REFERENCES ActiveDirectories(id)   <-- this needs to be a column of the ActiveDirectories table
```

Could it be that the column is called `ID` in the `Employees` table, and `UserID` in the `ActiveDirectories` table?

Then your command should be:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID)                   <-- column in table "Employees"
REFERENCES ActiveDirectories(UserID)   <-- column in table "ActiveDirectories"
```

Comment: I know its weird but unfortunately the name in the ActiveDirectory table id

Answer (score 5):

MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

To allow naming of a FOREIGN KEY constraint, and for defining a FOREIGN KEY constraint on multiple columns, use the following SQL syntax:

MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders
FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the future.

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD UserID int;

ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ActiveDirectories_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
    REFERENCES ActiveDirectories(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Faculty 
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FKFacultyBook
FOREIGN KEY FacId
REFERENCES Book Book_Id

ALTER TABLE Faculty 
WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FKFacultyStudent 
FOREIGN KEY FacId
REFERENCES Student StuId
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation with your answer

Answer (score 0):

way of foreign key creation correct for ActiveDirectories(id), i think the main mistake is you didn't mentioned primary key for id in ActiveDirectories table

Answer (score 0):

If the table has already been created:

First do:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table1_name` ADD UNIQUE( `column_name`);
```

Then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table1_name` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`column_name`) REFERENCES `table2_name`(`column_name`);
```