# How to refer to a table, which is not yet created?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I need to create two tables which both refer to each other (they need constraints).  Is the only way to create the tables without the constraints, and then add them in a separate statement? I remember that some orms can solve this themselves, but is it possible to do this only using sql and in two statements?

Comment: Create both tables first, then alter them to add `FK` like [SQL Add foreign key to existing column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389477/sql-add-foreign-key-to-existing-column)

Comment: This means that it is not possible to use schema dump to import schema.

Comment: For that case, probably you cant use schema dump.

Comment: Maybe you could treat this as an opportunity to rid yourself of this circular reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You <s>should</s> must create the tables first without foreign keys and append them after both tables are created:

```
create table t1 (id int not null primary key, id2 int not null);
create table t2 (id int not null primary key, id1 int not null);

alter table t1 add foreign key (id2) references t2(id);
alter table t2 add foreign key (id1) references t1(id);
```

Good news: A schema dump works perfect (`so` is my database):

```
mysqldump -u root so t1 t2 | mysql -u root so
```

This gives no errors because `mysqldump` inserts `DISABLE KEYS` and `ENABLE KEYS` at the right places.