# Unable to add a constraint foreign key to a table from an already created table in SQL server management studio 18. Can someone help me?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm creating a database for my assignment. I had to create 2 tables namely Customer and Job through the "New Query" option in SQL server. After creating both of them, I wanted to add Job_ID (A primary key) from Job table as a foreign key to the Customer table. As I have already created the Customer table, The only option I had was to ALTER the customer table. But after altering, I seemed to get this unusual error.

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Foreign key 'Job_ID' references invalid column 'Job_ID' in referencing table 'CUSTOMER'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I can provide you with any more info if necessary.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(Customer_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Customer_Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Gender CHAR(1),
Customer_Type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
Addresss VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Telephone_No CHAR(10) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE JOB
(Job_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Pickup_location VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
Destination VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
Customer_ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CUSTOMER(Customer_ID));

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Job_ID) REFERENCES JOB(Job_ID);
```

Comment: Table `customer` does not have `job_id` column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Add foreign key to existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389477/sql-add-foreign-key-to-existing-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389477/sql-add-foreign-key-to-existing-column).

When you try to create your foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Job_ID) REFERENCES JOB(Job_ID);
```

You are saying that you want to use the field `Job_ID` from the table `CUSTOMER`:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD FOREIGN KEY (Job_ID)
```

and that the values in this field should match values in the `Job_ID` column from the table `JOB`:

```
REFERENCES JOB(Job_ID);
```

The problem is that your `CUSTOMER` table doesn't have a `Job_ID` column, based on its definition:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(Customer_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Customer_Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Gender CHAR(1),
Customer_Type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
Addresss VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Telephone_No CHAR(10) NOT NULL);
```

The fields in the `CUSTOMER` table are `Customer_ID`,`Customer_Name`,`Gender`,`Customer_Type`,`Addresss` and `Telephone_No`.

So you either need to add a `Job_ID` column to the `CUSTOMER` table, or specify a different field to use in your `ALTER TABLE` statement - one which *does* exist in the `CUSTOMER` table.

More information on `ALTER TABLE` and `ADD FOREIGN KEY` specifically can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017).